# Error when sending data from AWS IoT to SQS FiFo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-iot

I have IoT devices that are sending data to AWS IoT Core, and from there I've created a rule that forwards the data (in JSON format) to SQS, where I have a FiFo queue set up. I'm getting failure with the following detail:

```
    "details": "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId. 
    (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter; 
     Request ID: 67c63eb5-d2b5-5d3e-8ffa-68cf304356de)"
```

It looks like i need to include MessageGroupID parameter, but how do I do that if my IoT devices aren't sending that information? Is there any way to add that parameter without updating the software running on the IoT devices?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you are trying to republish to SQS FIFO Queue using IoT Rules SQL when a message arrives in IoT Cloud.

First, let's understand why AWS needs **MessageGroupID** to be sent:

You will need to specify MessageGroupID in every message you (re)publish to a FIFO Queue in SQS.
*This is for grouping reasons during downstream message processing.*

Hence, you may assign:

> 1. A **hardcoded literal like "MY_MESSAGE_GROUP_ID"** to MessageGroupId for all republished messages, to have one and only one downstream process subscribe to these messages.
> 2. A **randomized UUID** to MessageGroupId, using **newuuid()** function in AWS IoT Rules [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-newuuid). This will create an opportunity to have multiple downstream processes subscribe to messages in parallel.

In both these cases, message FIFO order will be respected.

cheers,
ram

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on the assumption that what you are trying to achieve is

- create an Action rule in IoT Core
- forward your messages to a SQS FIFO queue

As per AWS SQS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sqs-rule-action.html), FIFO queues are not supported as endpoints of IoT Core actions:

> The SQS action doesn't support Amazon SQS FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queues. Because the rules engine is a fully distributed service, there is no guarantee of message order when the SQS action is triggered.